# 20.04 having trouble booting after recent updates

Tags: boot, zfs

Running 20.04 with zfs. Started machine and was working normally. Booted into plasma desktop. I tend to update as soon as I notice that the system has some to install. This morning the noticed a long list of updates. As I usually do updated all. Taking a call while the updates ran and something happened. Closed update window and started getting message about something crashing. Now I should have stopped everything and taken a picture of exactly what it was telling me had crashed but I didn't. I just went to the start menu and told it to reboot. But it wouldn't. So I went to the terminal and did a `shutdown -P` and that shut it down.

When I tried to reboot it just sat on the black screen with the cursor flashing in the upper left of the screen, stayed there for 10min before I held down power button and tried again. Went to advanced and tried all 4 versions of the Kernel couldn't get back to desktop. No problem got ZFS lets got back... looked at history... the most resent snapshot available was from 6/10/2020  ...the day I installed. Nothing between today and then. I didn't want to but I tried reverting back to that snapshot. It has been trying for over 40 minutes and doesn't look like it is going to go.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: why not reinstall without loosing data? There is a nice how-to on https://www.fosslinux.com/2920/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-by-keep-your-data-safe-in-event-of-system-failure.htm . It is for Ubuntu 17.10 but essentially the same as for 20.04